# Which DataFrame column names in other DataFrame column names in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a two `pyspark` `DataFrames` that have some overlap in column names. How can I see which column names are in the other? In `sparkr` I can do the following and it works:

```
colnames(df)[colnames(df) %in% colnames(df2)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Python` you can use list comprehension like this:

```
[c for c in df.columns if c in df2.columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets:

```
set(df.columns) & set(df2.columns)
```

To have list, put the expression above into a `list()`